# Black Edges in Transparent PNG in Photoshop Save for Web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, save

Is it possible to simply use Save for Web with resizing to produce images without black edges?

My current Save for Web setting

[image: Save for Web setting]

Left: original

Top right: Save for Web (black edges)

Middle right: bicubic resize then save

Bottom right: add a layer mask from transparency, resize then save (black edges)

[image: Overview]

Original

[image: Original]

Save for Web

[image: Save for web]

Resize then save

[image: Simple resize and save]

Add a layer mask from transparency, resize then save

[image: Layer mask, resize then save]

Comment: You could use better example images, white on white background is a bit hard.

Comment: The black edge is related to how the original image is stored. The color for the transparent pixels is black so Photoshop render the edge black when resizing in Save for Web. I have enlarged the overview for easier understanding.

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop CC 2015, the new Export As solves the problem. It does not produce black edges when resizing but the Save for Web (Legacy) still does.

Comment: I have been trying for days to solve this. The new Export As command DOES work. I create my all-white transparent icons by copying the white-on-black image into a blank channel, then I fill the whole layer with 100% white, then I load the alpha channel as a selection, and delete. (So, every pixel is white, no grey or black.) Then I do export > export as. Thanks for the help. I was going crazy.